# How do I remove multiple event listeners from a set of elements?

Tags: javascript, events

I have a set of button elements that once a condition is met i would like for them to become unresponsive.I figured that the **removeEventListener** should do the trick but after my **if statement** returns **true** the buttons are still clickable.

```
const field = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".field"))
    const boardData = [];
    
    field.forEach(button => {
        
        const func = (e) => {


            
            if(xTurn) {
                if(checkWin(player1)){
                    freezeBoard(field,func)
                };
            }
            
            else  {                                           
                if(checkWin(player2)){
                    freezeBoard(field,func)                        
                };
            }
        }
        button.addEventListener("click", func)
        
    })
    function freezeBoard(buttons,func) {
        buttons.forEach(button => {

            button.removeEventListener("click", func);           
        })
    }
```

Comment: you must declare `func` outside of the forEach loop to not recreate the function for each element

Answer (score 2):

Declare the `func` outside so you only have *one* created `func` - when you create it inside a loop, each listener uses a different reference, so `removeEventListener` doesn't work.

```
const field = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".field"))
const boardData = [];
const func = () => {
    if (xTurn) {
        if (checkWin(player1)) {
            freezeBoard(field, func)
        };
    } else {
        if (checkWin(player2)) {
            freezeBoard(field, func)
        };
    }
};
field.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", func)
})
function freezeBoard(buttons, func) {
    buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.removeEventListener("click", func);
    })
}
```

Could simplify by removing the arguments and condensing the condition.

```
const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".field"))
const boardData = [];
const func = () => {
    if ((xTurn && checkWin(player1) || checkWin(player2))) {
        freezeBoard(field, func);
    }
};
buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", func)
});
function freezeBoard(buttons) {
    buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.removeEventListener("click", func);
    })
}
```